# React navigation navigate after create a post

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Got Screen Restaurants(list of restaurants, here you can navigate to x restaurant) -> Restaurant screen, this is the normal way to access to a restaurant. Also after create a Restaurant(CreateRestaurantScreen). I want to navigate to the created restaurant and when press back button got restaurants screen instead of create restaurant.

Restaurants -> restaurant:id
CreateRestaurant -> restaurant:id <- back Restaurants instead of CreateRestaurant

I achieve this with the code below it works but don't know if there is another way to make this because my approach is slow

```
yield NavigationService.popToTop();
yield NavigationService.navigate(
            'ExploreOptions',
            { screen: 'ShowRestaurants' });
yield NavigationService.navigate(
            'ExploreOptions',
            { screen: 'ShowRestaurant', params: { id: restaurant._id, deepLink: false } });
```

Comment: Do you mean navigate to self using different params? (refersh) ?

Comment: No, I want to navigate to Screen Show Restaurant from Create Restaurant and inner show Restaurant I want with .goBack go to Show restaurants instead of create restaurant.

Comment: pass upper navigator goback as inner goback.